# MVC - Passing Model from Controller to a Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to send an e-mail from my controller calling a static function located in a class EmailHelper. As a parameter I want to use my model so I can call it just like that:

```
EmailHelper.SendEmail(MyModel model)
```

I just need to call that function in many places passing different models. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an interface to your model (for example IEmailModel)

```
public interface IEmailModel{
  string propertyUsedByHelper {get;set;}

}
public class MyModel: IEmailModel{
  public string propertyUsedByHelper {get;set;}

}
```

then your helper will do the trick

```
EmailHelper.SendEmail(IEmailModel model)

public static class EmailHelper {
  public void SendEmail(IEmailModel model)
  {
    IEmailModel m = model;
    string prop = m.propertyUsedByHelper;
  }
}
```

BTW your is a typical cross concern need, so the best method to manage this need is [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), take a look to interception in [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) or also [Castle dynamic proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. The only question is wouldn't it be violation of the idea of ViewModels? Every view model must implement all props defined in this interface so if one of my VM's had originally just one property now it will have as many as in the interface?

Comment: if you would implement the same functionality, you need to respect the contract of interface, implementing this by inheritance or by an abstract class(where you can define a default)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to have your specific model for email messages, and convert from your specific model inside the controller to the model used for email messages. This way the function can be reused regardless of both the model being used and the project.

One way to create an email model from your specific model and keep the code readable could be to use an Extension method class, providing conversion methods towards the email message

```
public static class EmailConverters
{
    public static EmailModel ToEmail(this MyModel model)
    {
        // Create a new EmailModel based on MyModel fields and return that
    }
}
```

this way on your controller you can write something like:

```
EmailHelper.SendEmail(model.ToEmail())
```

There are also other ways for doing this, specifically by using libraries such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and similar, but for an email message I would say they could be overkill.

Comment: +1 this is not a bad idea, something like an adapter